# How to do Notepad++ like folding in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

This is a folding custom area in Notepad++:

[image: Notepad++]

In Atom we are supposed to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. The issue is that after  unfolding it, the arrow disappears requiring us to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> again.

Is there a way I can use the brackets to achieve the same result in Atom as I did in Notepad++?

Comment: This seems to be sensitive to your language's syntax highlighting.  Typing the above and setting it to plain-text, I was able to get the collapse arrow (they are hidden and you have to hover over them); When I set the language to JavaScript though, the arrow wasn't there.

Comment: This plugin may help: https://atom.io/packages/custom-folds